# manual alphanumeric validation php

Tags: php

Is it more or less secure to create a large array of uppercase and lowercase letters, along with 0-9, plus any other allowed characters for form validation?  As opposed to using `ctype_alnum()`.  To protect against sql injection, that is.

**Example:**

```
<?php
    $inputValue = "{$userValue}";
    $set = array(a,b,c,d...A,B,C,D....0,1,2,3...);
    if(!in_array($inputValue, $set){
       echo "Please submit only letters or numbers.";
?>
```

Comment: I think binding prepared statements is the way to protect against injection. I also think if you want to validate letters and/or numbers, perhaps a regex would be better?

Comment: Hmm that would be a tedious thing to do since `in_array()` checks an existence of specific string. I would go with @Rasclatt 's suggestion

Comment: and or the escape functions specifically designed for data  base user added data

Comment: Thank You for the quick response.

Comment: i don't see any one mentioning: `ctype_alnum()` does NOT\CAN'T protect against sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't say this very often, but perhaps using [a regex check](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bYa) might be easier here:

```
if (preg_match('~[^\w\d]~', $inputValue)) {
    echo 'Please submit only letters or numbers.';
}
```

Alternatively if you stick with your current route, you could simplify your array declaration by doing something like this:

```
$set = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));
```

Comment: Is it more or less secure .. To protect against sql injection, that is.

Comment: I agree with the comments that if the objective is security against SQL injection then using tools that already exist (parameter binding, etc) would be a much more favourable option. Thought I'd just post this anyway as an alternative to what the OP provided.

Comment: Its just not even looking save. I created a function to block SQL injection efficiently. Its just manipulating the string until it fits my security standards.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no, there is no difference in security between the two options.  It's also worth mentioning that this is not suitable for protection against SQL injection - for that you should be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can use `real_escape_string`.

**In mysql**

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

Check this [Example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#refsect1-function.mysql-real-escape-string-examples) as well

**In Mysqli**

Read this [Example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#refsect1-mysqli.real-escape-string-examples)  as well

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($user);
```

Or use **`ctype_alnum()`** like this

Read this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php#refsect1-function.ctype-alnum-examples) as well

```
<?php
$inputValue = '$userValue';

    if (ctype_alnum($inputValue))
    {
        echo "Only letters and numbers A-Z, a-z and 0-10";
    } else
    {
        echo "Contain atleast one wrong letter";
    }

?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed in future.

Comment: @scrowler ya. of course. Thats why i mentioned **Mysqli** as well